# Set up Chef 11 and workstation. Knife suddenly creating cookbooks improperly, not finding knife.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, chef-solo, knife

I set up Chef 11 and configured knife on a workstation. Everything was working the last time I logged in and I successfully created several cookbooks and synced them to the Chef server.

Now, all of a sudden when I create a cookbook ("WARNING: No knife configuration file found"):

```
root@server1:/# knife cookbook create postsetup
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
** Creating cookbook postsetup
** Creating README for cookbook: postsetup
** Creating CHANGELOG for cookbook: postsetup
** Creating metadata for cookbook: postsetup
```

This results in the cookbook being created in the default location. It is as if knife is suddenly ignoring the knife.rb:

```
root@server1:/# find -iname "*postsetup*"
./var/chef/cookbooks/postsetup
```

Knife.rb file (The only knife.rb file. Problem still happens even after doing a fresh 'knife configure'):

```
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                'workstation'
client_key               '/root/chef-repo/.chef/workstation.pem'
validation_client_name   'chef-validator'
validation_key           '/root/chef-repo/.chef/chef-validator.pem'
chef_server_url          'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443'
syntax_check_cache_path  '/root/chef-repo/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path [ '/root/chef-repo/cookbooks' ]
```

What is going on with the knife utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by moving my knife.rb and pertinent files to /root/.chef. It appears knife now only wants to look in this location, despite fiddling with some of the parameters. :)

Comment: The chef documentation describes how the default location for config file is ~/.chef/knife.rb (See: https://docs.getchef.com/config_rb_knife.html)

Comment: Indeed it does. Strange that it presents a custom knife.rb location in the 'configure' option, and that it functioned using this location until an arbitrary point in time with no noteworthy changes inbetween. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.